# preg match extract digits from string after pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of the form

```
<something>_string_t_<digits>
```

How can I extract just the `<digits>` portion in PHP ? I need to detect the string_t first and then pull out the digits.

Comment: Give us real strings. This is not enough

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: please be more specifi. Is digits an element of yours or are they numerical digits? What exactly do you need how far can this go, can there be other chars within the digits, what is the context and so so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$captures;
preg_match('/string_t_(\d+)/', $string, $captures);
do_something($captures[1]);
```

`$captures[1]` will contain `<digits>` (assuming `<digits>` is composed entirely of numbers - if it's not, use the more general `(.+)` in place of `(\d+)`).

Comment: You got $string and pattern in the wrong order

Comment: Quite right, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: that worked ! thanks !